# how to configure mailhog on windows

Tags: windows, mailhog

I want to set up mailhog on my windows laptop.
I downloaded the executable added it to the path.when I'm using the URL **localhost:8025**, it works just fine, opens up mailhog,but I won't get any messages in the inbox, I think the problem is with **mhsendmail**, I edited the **php.ini** file so it is set to the mhsendmail folder where **mhsendmail.exe** is also I set **smtp_port=1025**,but it still won't work,what do I need to do ?

Comment: Do manually sent e-mails appear? See also [this article](https://kinsta.com/de/blog/mailhog/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to open php.ini file and where it says
"sendmail_path = " you add the path of your "mhsendmail" .exe file.
I know it says "For Unix only" but it worked for me.